# Ghostscript 9.18 (gswin64c.exe) crashes when -dNumRenderingThreads > 1

Tags: pdf, tiff, ghostscript

I have the following problem converting a multipage pdf to tiff:

```
gswin64c.exe -dNumRenderingThreads=8 -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=tiffscaled -sCompression=g4 -r300 -o out.tiff in.pdf
```

`in.pdf` is a multi-page pdf with embedded images (i.e. scanned pages).

The command crashes (not always on the same page though) in my Windows 64 bit environment when running from the command line ("gswin64c.exe stopped working"), no STDERR is written to the console.  I use the newest Ghostscript version (9.18).

I can do the conversion just fine ONLY if I use `-dNumRenderingThreads=1`.

What could be the reason for this?

EDIT: With version 9.15, the conversion runs fine, starting from 9.16 it's not working anymore.

The System log error-entry says:

```
Faulting application name: gswin64c.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56123d41
Faulting module name: gsdll64.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56123d3d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000007b930
Faulting process id: 0x197c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d16325677e4e24
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin64c.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gsdll64.dll
Report Id: a7fd06f0-cf18-11e5-9ab2-028037ec0200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be a bug. There have been recent changes in this area so you could pull the latest code from Git, build and test that.

Or you can report a bug but if its not consistently reproducible it'll be difficult to fix.

NB You probably have too many threads there, and experimentation reveals little benefit from NumRenderingThreads anyway.